# Cannot specify default sort direction for datatable

Tags: django, datatables

I use [datatable](http://datatables.net/usage/columns) to list my data. I would like to define default sort column( creation date of list items). In my django view I send my data in descending order like this

```
MyObjects.objects.order_by('-create_date')
```

even if I turned down sort(using bSortable) on creation date column my template changes the sort order to ascending. I tried to use asSorting property but it works after the first click on table header. what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you use aaSorting property properly [datatables example](http://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html)
2. Check if your method for preparing datatables record has appriopriate piece of code to handle default sorting